# Using Pandas to convert CSV data to numbers when concatenating into excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am writing a small program to concatenate a load of measurements from multiple csv files. into one excel file. I have pretty much all the program written and working, the only thing i'm struggling to do is to get the data from the csv files to automatically turn into numbers when the dataframe places them into the excel file.
The code I have looks like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import glob


os.chdir(r"directoryname") 

retval = os.getcwd()

print ("Directory changed to %s" % retval)

files = glob.glob(r"directoryname\datafiles*csv") 

print(files)

files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))   
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')       
df = pd.read_csv("datafile.csv", index_col=False)  
df = df.iloc[0:41, 1]   
df.to_excel(writer, 'sheetname', startrow =0, startcol=1, index=False)

for f in files: 
i+=1
 df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False) 
 df = df.iloc[0:41,2]
 df.to_excel(writer, 'sheetname', startrow=0, startcol=1+i, index=False)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
df.loc[:,'measurements'] = df.loc[:,'measurements'].astype(float)
```

So when you read the dataframe you can cast all your columns like that for example.

Different solution is, while reading your csv to cast the columns by using dtypes (see [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

**EXAMPLE**

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(savepath,'test.csv') , sep=";" , dtype={
ID' : 'Int64' , 'STATUS' : 'object' } ,encoding = 'utf-8' )
```